# Why is this margin of error problem wrong?

Tags: statistics

[image]

$M.OE = (2.75)*(2.7)/\sqrt{n}\;$?

Comment: Where did you get $2.75$ from?

Comment: z = 2.575 (the area corresponding to 99% confidence interval assuming normal distribution )

Comment: So then it would be z=2.199? but that is also wrong.

Comment: You should be using a t-distribution when the sample size is small and the population standard deviation is not known.

Comment: And you should be dividing by $\sqrt n$ as you sample size gets larger your margin of error gets smaller.

Comment: @DougM could you please show how to get the t-distribution? Would the rest be the same and multiplied by the t-distribution

Comment: I meant to put a division sign in there

Comment: Is the answer 2.775?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t = \frac {\mu - \bar x}{s/\sqrt n}$

$\mu - \bar x$ is the margin of error. (true mean - sample mean)

$s$ is the sample standard deviation.

Then you look up on a table or use a statistical calculator to find the range of t for your confidence interval, and the "degrees of freedom" $(n-1)$ and as either a $1$ tail or $2$ tailed test.

$99$% and $9$ degrees of freedom and $2$-tailed test give
$|t|<3.25$

$|\mu - \bar x| < \frac {3.25 \cdot 2.7}{\sqrt {10}} = 2.77$

Comment: The answer needs to be rounded to $3$ decimal points, so it should be $2.775$ instead. :-)

Comment: 3 decimal points of accuracy on the margin of error that is 3 points wide? (and an initial estimate with 1 decimal pt of accuracy)  That false precision!  But yes, 2.775 would be the correct expansion.

Comment: Doug M: True, but question is asked to give the answer with $3$ decimals (please read the last sentence of the question).

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, when $n\leq30$ we should use a $t$-distribution rather than a normal distribution.

With a $t$ distribution our confidence interval is given by

$$\bar{X}\pm t \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$

with degrees of freedom $$df=n-1$$

I leave it to you to find the necessary $t$ value using a $t$-table.